# Attempting to categorize output from Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'am making a website that is supposed to work as a to-do/schedule-manager. The user can create different tasks which will be saved in local storage and outputed on the screen. Though I have been able to do this, I've added tabs that are supposed to categorize the different tasks made and this is where I am not getting the right output.

The goal is to make the tasks only appear on the right tab which they belong to categorically. As to now, the website only prints the tasks on one of the tabs and omits the name of the category and "beskrivelse"(description).

Here is the js-code:

```
// gets data from localStorage
function renderTask(){
    const taskOutput = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];

    const taskOutputEl = document.getElementById("combinedOutput");
    const taskOutputEl2 = document.getElementById("combinedOutput2");
    const taskOutputEl3 = document.getElementById("combinedOutput3");
    const taskOutputEl4 = document.getElementById("combinedOutput4");
    taskOutputEl.innerHTML = "";
    //taskOutputEl2.innerHTML = "";
    //taskOutputEl3.innerHTML = "";
    //taskOutputEl4.innerHTML = "";

    for (const task of taskOutput) {
        const taskEl = document.createElement("div");
        const {participant, duetime, description} = task;


        taskEl.innerHTML = "<div style = 'border: 1px solid black'> <strong> Deltaker(e): </strong> " + participant +
                            "<br> <strong> Frist: </strong> " + duetime + "<br>" + 
                            "<strong> Beskrivelse: </strong> " + description + "<div><br>";

        /*if (document.querySelector('#dropdown').value == 'school'){
            taskEl.innerHTML = "<div> Fag: " + subject + "<br> Deltaker(e): " + participant +
            "<br> Frist: " + duetime + "<br>" + 
            "Beskrivelse: " + description + "<div><br>";
        } else {
            taskEl.innerHTML = "<div> Deltaker(e): " + participant +
                            "<br> Frist: " + duetime + "<br>" + 
                            "Beskrivelse: " + description + "<div><br>";
        } */

        if (document.querySelector("#dropdown").value == "work"){
            taskOutputEl.appendChild(taskEl);

        } else if (document.querySelector("#dropdown").value == "subjects"){
            taskOutputEl2.appendChild(taskEl);

        } else if (document.querySelector("#dropdown").value == "various"){
            taskOutputEl3.appendChild(taskEl);

        } else{
            taskOutputEl4.appendChild(taskEl);
        } 


    taskOutputEl.appendChild(taskEl);
    //taskOutputEl2.appendChild(taskEl);
    //taskOutputEl3.appendChild(taskEl);
    //taskOutputEl4.appendChild(taskEl);


    }



/*
     if (document.querySelector("#dropdown").value == "work"){
            taskOutputEl.appendChild(taskEl);
        } else if (document.querySelector("#dropdown").value == "subjects"){
            taskOutputE2.appendChild(taskE1);
        } else if (document.querySelector("#dropdown").value == "various"){
            taskOutputE3.appendChild(taskE1);
        } else{
            taskOutputE4.appendChild(taskE1);
        } */

    }

// adds data to localStorage
function addTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const dropdown = document.querySelector("[name = 'dropdown']").value;
    const participant = document.querySelector("[name = 'participant']").value;
    const duetime = document.querySelector("[name = 'duetime']").value;
    const description = document.querySelector("[name = 'description']").value;

    const task = {dropdown, participant, duetime, description};

    const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];
    taskList.push(task);

    window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskList));
    renderTask();

    event.target.reset();
}

// runs when new inputs get added
window.addEventListener("storage", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "taskList") {
            renderTask();
        }
});

// output will stay even when user update the page
renderTask();
```

If I have broken any conventions for posting on this site I would appreciate feedback as well. 
If the HTML-code is needed then I'll add that too if requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in my group managed to fix it by changing the conditions in the if-Elses (which is now a switch)

```
// gets data from localStorage
function renderTask(){
    const taskOutput = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];

    const taskOutputEl = document.getElementById("combinedOutput");
    const taskOutputEl2 = document.getElementById("combinedOutput2");
    const taskOutputEl3 = document.getElementById("combinedOutput3");
    const taskOutputEl4 = document.getElementById("combinedOutput4");
    taskOutputEl.innerHTML = "";
    taskOutputEl2.innerHTML = "";
    taskOutputEl3.innerHTML = "";
    taskOutputEl4.innerHTML = "";

    for (const task of taskOutput) {
        const taskEl = document.createElement("div");
        const {participant, duetime, description, } = task;

        // the output text
        taskEl.innerHTML = "<div style = 'border: 1px solid black' draggable = 'true'> <strong> Deltaker(e): </strong> " + participant +
                            "<br> <strong> Frist: </strong> " + duetime + "<br>" + 
                            "<strong> Beskrivelse: </strong> " + description + "<div>";

        // into the different subjects
        switch (document.querySelector("#category").value && task.category) {
            case "work":
                taskOutputEl.appendChild(taskEl);
                break;

            case "subjects":
                taskOutputEl2.appendChild(taskEl);   
                break;

            case "hobby":
                taskOutputEl3.appendChild(taskEl);
                break;

            case "various":
                taskOutputEl4.appendChild(taskEl);
                break;
        }

    }


    }

// adds data to localStorage
function addTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const category = document.querySelector("[name = 'category']").value;
    const participant = document.querySelector("[name = 'participant']").value;
    const duetime = document.querySelector("[name = 'duetime']").value;
    const description = document.querySelector("[name = 'description']").value;

    const task = {category, participant, duetime, description};

    const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];
    taskList.push(task);

    window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskList));
    renderTask();

    event.target.reset();
}

// runs when new inputs get added
window.addEventListener("storage", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "taskList") {
            renderTask();
        }
});

// output will stay even when user update the page
renderTask();
```